# javascript enable and disable a combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I am a beginner in java-script , what  I am doing right here is trying to make my combo-box named "dale" to enable and disable when i select "Reasons Specific Categorized" from my combo-box named "repSelect" but i keep getting an error on my java-script.

> `function makeEnable(value){
>       if(value=="rep4"){
>       var x=document.getElementById("dale")
>       x.disabled=false
>       }else{
>       var x=document.getElementById("dale")
>       x.disabled=true
>           }
>       }
>       </script>
>       </script>
>       <select  onChange="makeEnable(value)" name="repSelect">
>       <option value="rep1">Employee</option>
>       <option value="rep2">Category Reasons Overall </option>
>       <option value="rep3">Department Overall </option>
>       <option  value="rep4">Reasons Specific Categorized </option>
>
>       </select>
>       <select  name="dale">
>       <option value="rep1">dale</option>
>       </select>
>           <input class="button" type="submit" value="Generar Reporte" >
>
>           </form>`

My modification But dosent work

> `function makeEnable(){
>       var e = document.getElementById("repSelect");
>       var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
>       if(strUser=="rep4"){
>       document.getElementById("dale").disabled=false;
>       }else{
>       document.getElementById("dale").disabled=true;
>       }
>   }`

Comment: Include the error that you get.

Comment: I modified it a bit i will put it in the question but i still nothing happends my "dale" combobox is still enabled

Comment: Your javascript is not able to find "id" named "dale"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `.getElementById()` method, but your element doesn't have an id defined. Add an id in the html:

```
<select id="dale" name="dale">
```

You may also need to modify the call to your function in the first select's `onchange` handler, to pass `this.value` instead of just `value`:

```
<select onChange="makeEnable(this.value)" name="repSelect">
```

You can also substantially simplify your function as follows:

```
function makeEnable(value){
    document.getElementById("dale").disabled = value!="rep4";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3t16p5p9/

EDIT: I just noticed that you had the jquery tag on your question. To use jQuery, remove the inline `onChange=` attribute and then add this to your script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name=repSelect]").change(function() {
        $("#dale").prop("disabled", this.value!="rep4");
    }).change();
});
```

This binds a change handler to the first select, and then calls it immediately so that the second one will be appropriately enabled or disabled when the page loads (as requested in a comment).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3t16p5p9/2/

Comment: It works in the demo I provided. Do you get any errors in your browsers console? Are you sure the function is actually getting called at all?

Comment: The simplest way is just to add a `disabled` attribute in the html:http://jsfiddle.net/3t16p5p9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using document.getElementById but your combobox doesn't have an Id.

Thats the reason its not working.

Instead of adding onchange in the html, use as below:

```
<select id='repselect' onchange=makeEnable() name="repSelect">
  <option value="rep1">Employee</option>
  <option value="rep2">Category Reasons Overall </option>
  <option value="rep3">Department Overall </option>
  <option  value="rep4">Reasons Specific Categorized </option>

  </select>
  <select id="seldale" name="dale">
  <option value="rep1">dale</option>
  </select>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Generar Reporte"/>
$('#repselect').change(function(){
  if(this.value=="rep4"){
  var x= document.getElementById("seldale")
  x.disabled=false
  }else{
  var x =document.getElementById("seldale")
  x.disabled=true
      }
  });
```

Comment: yes but i get an error when im passing my variable trough the parameter

Comment: user3263194 - Why would this work any better than using the variable `x` as shown in the question?

Comment: can u put it as an answer plz is that i dont get it sorry